# atom cannot indent line continuation

Tags: atom-editor

Why atom cannot indent this python code? Is there an extension to do it?

[image]

On the right you can see emacs behaviour, simply pressing tab on the second line, while atom is not indenting it.

## Update

I have disabled all the community extensions and this is what I get:

[image]

as you can see one space is missing. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

What are you exactly doing? I was able to indent it by using tab, using these steps:

1. Write a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
2. Using back arrow I went on position after 3.
3. Press enter.
4. Press tab

I was also able to do it if I wrote [1, 2, 3, and then pressed enter and tab.

Comment: I am doing exactly what you say. I have disabled all the extensions (except the lint*). I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Atom doesn't currently do this natively. Try using this package: https://atom.io/packages/python-indent